# Question regarding probability of an event.

Tags: probability

Let's say we have a bowl with 10 balls, 5 of them are black and 5 of them are white.We pick up three of them at the same time, what is the probability that not all of them are white if one of them is white?

Let's say that $A$ is an event in which at least one of the balls is white and $B$ is an event where not all three of them are white, therefore $B^C$ is event where all balls we picked are white, from here, we have:

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(AB)}{P(A)}$$ Since $B^C$ is easier to handle we have:

$$P(B|A)=1-P(B^C|A)=1-\frac{P(AB^C)}{P(A)}$$

This should not be much of a problem, however, when when i am trying to determine $P(A)$ i have the following:

Probability of an event is number of positive outcomes divided by all outcomes.

therefore $P(A)=\frac{ {5 \choose 1} {9 \choose 2} }{10 \choose 3}$. However this turns out to be $1.5$ (i checked my calculations several times and found no mistakes) which makes no sense, so im stuck here. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You calculated the number of ways to choose at least one white ball as $\binom51\binom92$. That should give the number of ways to first pick $1$ object from among $5$, then pick $2$ from among $9$, i.e., first pick a white ball, then pick $2$ other balls. The problem is that this formula double-counts a lot of cases. For example, let's say the balls you've picked are White Ball P, White Ball Q, and Black Ball Z. Then you've counted picking P and then picking Q&Z, but you've also counted separately picking Q and then picking P&Z, while they describe the same case.

You can fix this by separating into different cases depending on how many white balls you pick, but it'll be easier to apply the same strategy you applied at a different point in the problem and calculate $P(A) = 1 -P(A^c)$.

Comment: Beat me by 14 seconds! :)

Comment: Ok, thanks, this was quick and well  explained, same goes for Bram28s answer!

Answer (score 3):

You are double-counting the number of ways to get at least one white ball with the ${5 \choose 1} {9 \choose 2} $

Say one white ball is $W_1$ and another is $W_2$. Now, when you pick $W_1$ as 'one of the $5$ white balls', and then pick 'two more out of the remaining $9$', you can of course end up picking $W_2$ as one of those other two.  But, if you first pick $W_2$ as one of the five whites, and then pick two more, you can pick $W_1$ as one of the two other ones ... and thus possibly end up with the very same three balls. But you count them as two different outcomes.

Indeed, if all three balls are white, you end up triple-counting the same one outcome.